# how can i delete a git repo without removing the files in it

Tags: git, github

i dont want to remove the files but just the old repository. everytime i go to commit it, it wont let me because its part of another repository

````
C:\Users\travi\Desktop\github 1.16>git commit -a
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
        modified:   mods (modified content, untracked content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")```
````

Comment: You've got a git repo inside a git repo. If you wish one of them was no longer a repo, find the repo (it is an invisible folder called _.git_) and throw it in the trash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have, by mistake, initialized a Git repository in `C:\Users\travi\Desktop\`

```
dir C:\Users\travi\Desktop\.git
```

It yes, you could delete that one, leaving only `C:\Users\travi\Desktop\github 1.16\.git`, meaning: a Git repository in your current project, instead of a parent folder of that project.